# What does Pid xxx over core_pipe_limit mean?

Tags: ubuntu, crash

My Laptop froze and I killed the Window manager using ctrl + alt + backspace.
Now I am reading the journal entries. There it says

```
  kernel: Pid xxx over core_pipe_limit
  kernel: Skipping core dump
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel usually generates a [core dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) (i.e. a memory dump) for crashing processes, where all memory used by that process is stored on disk for later analysis. The message means that the system has reached a limit of number of simultaneous core dumps being processed (which is usually 16, meaning that more than 16 processes have crashed at once and the system can't store the dumps fast enough).

Traditionally it was just a file named "core" or "core.[id]", but with systemd, it's managed via `coredumpctl` – instead of directly writing to a file, the kernel gives the entire core dump to the "systemd-coredump" process, which then compresses the dump and logs various extracted information to the journal. The "core_pipe_limit" parameter tries to prevent the system from being overwhelmed by too many instances of "systemd-coredump" (especially as they all occupy additional memory while processing the dump).

For now, ignore the message and just look at the ones immediately above (indicating which processes crashed). Keep in mind that sometimes apps might crash simply because they lost connection to the display server due to Ctrl+Alt+Backspace and they weren't programmed to handle that.